# Postman - Adding parameters in between

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using Postman to test the API using POST request. I have added multiple parameters in POST request. I am following sequence as specified in form. I have missed some of the parameters in between.

E.g: I want to add multiple parameters in between **s_LastName** and **s_ReplacementCost** from below image.

Is it possible to add those parameters in between ?

[image]

Comment: the order should't matter?

Comment: @oswald yes i know that. But I want to follow the sequence so it becomes easier to track.

Comment: May you can export as json, edit the json and import it again?

Comment: There's a 'hamburger' icon that pops up, to the left of the checkbox, to arrange the order of those values. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @DannyDainton Hamburger only arranges the fields. I was looking after the way to add the multiple parameters in between.

Comment: add a new one, move it to where you need it in the ones you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can *move* the different params. Add the new ones to the bottom of the form, then use the *hambuger* icon and drag them to the desired location.

Alternatively, add the new values to the form, select the 'Bulk Edit' option and cut and paste them into the desired location.

[image: Postman]

Comment: Thanks @Danny_Dainton. Bulk Edit made it easier to add fields in between.